# Phonegap Localstorage api understanding

Tags: database, cordova, local-storage

From the example taken directly from phonegap.

```
function queryDB(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function successCB() {
  var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
  db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}
```

Im wondering what is this "tx"?

Is TX 100% needed to have as parameter?

Im seeking some understanding, im a bit confused with this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Phonegap example the tx parameter is the data that come from db.transaction >> populateDB parameter

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

// Populate the database 
//
function populateDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}
```

**EDIT:**

I found this article to may help you. This explains you how to connect your Phonegap app to your server database.

[Adding Database Synchronization to Your PhoneGap Project](http://css.dzone.com/articles/adding-database)

Comment: i havent been able to find much info on this subject.  I am currently trying to make a costum insert and get data piece of code.

Comment: I solved the matter with insert.  Its in that link you posted.  So for everyone else reading this, read that link above :)

thanks again Maga :)

Answer (score 0):

So lets assume that i wanted to write my own insert sql function, that recieved data from a HTML form.

then i would "HAVE TO" no exceptions do this.. ?

```
function costumInsert() {
  db.transaction(myInsert, errorCB, successCB);
}

function myInsert(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO....);
}
```

Comment: I suppose that works only if you have the database on your device.